# Resolving CS0649 warning in c#

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

The compiler is showing warning CS0649 at line 5

```
public class DescoService
{
    CommonUtilityService utilityServiceObject;
    DescoBill descoBillObjcet;
    private string VTransactionSerialNo = ""; //warning here
    int AccessFlag;

    public DescoService()
    {
        utilityServiceObject = new CommonUtilityService();
        descoBillObjcet = new DescoBill();
        //VTransactionSerialNo = "";
    }
}
```

I assigned it an empty string but the warning still shows.How to resolve this?

Comment: It still shows this warning even when you rebuild the project?

Comment: Rebuilding solved it.I was just building it i guess.But i had to add the readonly modifier as well.Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

If you define variables without using it, you will get this error. So you have to use it, give it a null value, give it an initial value or remove it. and also you can disable this warning by doing the following.

For disable, the warning

```
#pragma warning disable 0649
```

To return it to the previous state

```
#pragma warning restore 0649
```

It is not recommended to disable the warning because it will effect on the compiler process. So, I recommend you to fix the warning as mentioned early.

Comment: Disabling warnings should always be the last resort. It's not something to be done under most circumstances. By disabling a warning, you're telling the compiler that you know better than it. And onsidering some really smart people wrote the compiler and they put a lot of thought into these warnings, it's best to listen to them.

Comment: @mason you are absolutely right, but it is just a solution if you have many variables and you need to get rid of this message.

Comment: Having many variables isn't a good reason to disable the compiler warning. You need a far better reason than that.

Comment: @ I already tell that he needs to use the defined variable, give it a null value, give it an initial value or remove it. and also you can disable this warning.

Comment: Yes, but you have no advice regarding which to use or why, or the danger of disabling warnings . You just casually mentioned it. Keep in mind, not everyone that reads your answer is going to know the danger of disabling warnings. In fact, if they search for this warning and end up at that question, it's very likely they don't know the danger.

Answer (score 0):

I just *cleaned* the solution and the warning went away.